# Calling external application in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm going to write a user interface for [clocker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clocker). clocker is a CLI-based issue time tracker. As far as I know, clocker is a nodejs stand-alone application, and it doesn't have any programming interface. for example, to start tracking time for an issue named **123**, the command will be something like:

```
clocker start -t 123
```

I'm new to Angular and I don't know how to call clocker as an external application in my own angular app. I've searched a lot, but all of them are explaining how to call an external library, but here I don't have any programming interface.

Comment: You could use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/moro

Comment: @SachinYadav Thank you, but what's the difference between moro and clocker, both of them are stand-alone applications which should be called in my app.

Comment: I know i was trying to implement but couldn't find a solution to your question so sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to have your own Backend that runs Node.js and interact with the Angular by Restful APIs.

You can check [this](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express/) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, the link was great. I'm waiting for more answers, then I'll accept the best one. :)